# Unable to place my div in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a div and in the div i have placed an image. I am trying to position that div in the center of the page but am unable to. Please help me. Thanks !

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        .bannerimage {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bannerimage">
        <img src="images/mailer2.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` for your `bannerimage` class to center it easily. Hope this helps

```
.bannerimage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Comment: I now want to give padding to the container. I have given the padding but it doesn't seem to work. Could you please see what am I doing wrong here ? Thanks
     .bannerimage {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: -webkit-fill-available;
                padding: 20px;
            }

Comment: Try adding a wrapper div to the image. Check this fiddle. Hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/1f83dqkn/

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
     display:block;
     margin:  auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bannerimage">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" width="150px;" height="150px;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Check this code.I think this is what you want.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can as already written use `display:flex;`
but there are other ways:

```
* {
 margin : 0;
 padding : 0;
 }


.bannerimage {
 margin : 0 auto;
 min-width : 20%;
 max-width : 1000px;
 text-align : center;
 backgroud : #000;
 }
```

What i´ve done is to give the .bannerimage a min- and max-width attribute, 
you also could use width instead.

Edit:

Sine i don´t know the resolution of your image this was basic example 
of how to use margin only to show you how to "center" the div itself.

Now that´s everbodys voting down without even thinking of this point: 
here is a fiddle, with working code! OMG!

https://jsfiddle.net/kymd1jv7/

If you don´t give this class a specific width most browsers will
handle this class as it will have a width of 100%.

The "image" could als be centered with `text-align : center;`

Comment: This isn't even right. Here is a fiddle with your code inside it, which you should have done yourself. https://jsfiddle.net/oc53bxaf/

Comment: You are joking? This will center the div class, not the image. If you add a background color or as written text-align : center it will center the image as well.

Comment: build a working fiddle with your css and the asker's posted markup.

Comment: so add the proper css to your answer

Comment: The text-align : center; was mentioned at first! Everything i´ve really added was a background color to show that the div itself is declared.

Comment: There. Providing complete snippets and creating a working example are part of providing a good answer to a question. And look, your downvotes magically went away.

Comment: And it´s gone. You´re right at this point, that is something i´ve to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of ways and this is in addition from https://stackoverflow.com/users/362477/iamnotsam

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        .bannerimage {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width:100px;

        }
        body{
          height:100%;
        }
        .content {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bannerimage">
        <img class="content" src="images/mailer2.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `transform` property. Keep in mind that the parent div should be `relative`

```css
.bannerimage {
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
            border:1px solid red
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="bannerimage">
        <img src="images/mailer2.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a container with a set width, (width: 100% or display: flex)

> You can set the margin property to auto to horizontally center the
>   element within its container.
>
> The element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining
>   space will be split equally between the left and right margins:
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

```css
 .container{
   display:flex;
 }
 #bannerimage {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/" id="bannerimage">
    </div>
</body>
```